# Django saving an image that is a model field, works on /admin but not custom upload page

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, model-view-controller, file-upload

Rather than using Django admin, I wanted to make my own images upload on my site at `127.0.0.1/upload`

Now, when I upload an image through the admin, it works fine. But when I upload though my own image, it's not uploading (and not to the correct path).

**template**

```
<form action="{% url 'app:publish' %}" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="file" name="image_upload" accept="image/*" />
     <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def publish(request):
    image = request.POST.get('image_upload', '')
    photo = Photo(image=image)
    photo.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

**models.py**

```
def generate_path(self, filename):
    url = "%s/%s" % (self.college.name, filename)
    return url

class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_path, default="buildingimages/default.png")
```

This is was I usually do for text based fields, but I'm assuming files work differently, and that's why this is not working?

The object shows up in my admin after I try my upload, but the image itself doesn't seem to upload nor go to the right directory.

So the generate_path works totally fine when I upload through the admin, but through my own publish view, it seems to upload to /media/ and then it says image does not exist?

Any idea what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Image Uploading - Uploads do not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274700/django-image-uploading-uploads-do-not-work)

Answer (score 1):

Uploaded files are stored in `request.FILES`, not in `request.POST`.

Comment: So would it be request.FILES.get? I tried that and now the image is not uploaded at all.

Comment: Yes, is your form of type `multipart/form-data`? You have a lot of tutorials on how to upload images with django, i.e. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html