# Django form doesn't validate - ValueError sending pdf

Tags: python, html, django, forms, pdf

Django form doesn't validate, have no idea why. Originally I supposed it was because I added one more hidden input filed to the form(is is actually allowed? found nothing related in docs ) but I deleted it and nothing changed.

the form:

```
class TicketForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Ticket
    fields = ('upload','ownership','price','comment','ticket_type')
    widgets = {
        'upload': forms.FileInput(
            attrs={'id': 'fileinput', 'required': True, 'name':'pdf', 'placeholder': 'Say something...'}
        ),
    }
```

model:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='media/tickets/')
    ownership = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sold = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    TICKET_CHOICES = (
        ('DG', 'Digital'),
        ('RL', 'Real'),
    )  
    ticket_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=TICKET_CHOICES,
        default='Digital',
    )
```

in template:

```
    <form method='POST' action="/upload_ticket/" class="pdf_form">
{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}

      <!-- <input type="hidden" id="pk_input" value="{{ selected.id}}" name="event_id"></input> -->
      <input type="submit" id='submit_hidden'>Save</input>
  </form>
```

In views if I remove `if form.is_valid()`
the error is obvious `The Ticket could not be created because the data didn't validate.`

The file to be loaded is pdf file.

Do you have any ideas why it doesn't validate?

Comment: What errors does the form show?

Comment: @DanielRoseman traceback isn't very helpful. only that error line   ticket = form.save(commit=False)

Comment: @DanielRoseman generally it's 'ValueError at /upload_ticket/' but why should it be, it's file input and pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Image Uploading - Uploads do not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274700/django-image-uploading-uploads-do-not-work)